# How do I delete the site specific form information on Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, developer-tools

What I have tried:

1. Explored the Chrome settings but all I see is Forms auto-fill that mostly gave addresses et al information.
2. I deleted the cookies for the site too. But does not seem to be working.

[image: Github Form Autofill Dropdown Chrome]

But I am not able to remove the dropdown autofills on the website as seen in above image.

Answer (score 0):

the suggested item in dropdown is not come from cookies, i think its come from browser case, so fare you need to clear browser case using chrome API. please refer this like for refrance.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Clear Storage](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage#clear-storage) pane. Make sure that all of the checkboxes are enabled.